# onScroll method not working

Tags: java, android

```
public class showManga extends Activity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{

GestureDetectorCompat detector;
TextView text; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    setContentView(R.layout.image);
    this.detector=new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.detector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2,
        float arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    text.setText("scroll");
    return true;

}
@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}



}
```

I don't understand why this code not working. I checked everything. It seems right to me. Please help me. The `onScroll` method not working.

Comment: Feel free to explain what "not working" means for you.

Comment: -1 for very (un)explicit title. (not working is not really more explicit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place this line after setcontent view

```
text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

**like :**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.image);
 text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    this.detector=new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
}
```